# WPF wired Rectangle with Resource Icon ResourceDictoinary Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, binding, resourcedictionary

I'm working on a WPF app, and trying to give a button an icon from Icons ResourceDictionary

I created a new ResourceDictionary Merge the Icons ResourceDictionary, and created a few Button Rectangle Styles to use. 
And then I found out I can't directly bind the Icon to VisualBrush, I have to create another VisualBrush ResourceKey to show the icon. 
I listed working and not working code below.

Anybody know the explanation of this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Binding xaml:

```
<Button Width="80" Height="80">
    <Rectangle Style="{DynamicResource Icon14040}"></Rectangle>
</Button>
```

Not Working Style:

```
<Style x:Key="Icon14040" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource Icon1}"></VisualBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Working Style:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="Icon1Brush4040" Visual="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
<Style x:Key="Icon14040" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Icon1Brush4040" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Oddly, they are similar. For me, two constructions work. Tested within the style in `Window.Resources.` For the working case can also write: `<Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Icon1Brush4040}" />`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev I thought they are the same, but the result surprised me, and really confused.